# CakePHP question: Can't connect to database, what can be the reason?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

First line of the error =>

```
Access denied for user 'user_user'@'real.superdnssite.com' (using password: YES) [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.p
```

database.php =>

```
var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'a.b.c.d',
    'login' => 'user_user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
);

var $test = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'a.b.c.d',
    'login' => 'user_user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'database_name',
    'prefix' => '',
);
```

What can be the reason for this ? Is it for wrong password or for no database or for ip address ?

Comment: Have you given this user access to 'database_name' (db) from your cPanel...?>

Comment: did you try to connect to db via mysql|_connect? maybe problem in credentials

Comment: I rechecked database.php for typo, and now it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

`'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql'`